# Ionic 2 Radio button (<ion-radio>) showing only the button and nothing else

Tags: html, typescript, angular, ionic2

Im trying to implement a list with radio buttons using the ion-list and ion-radio directives. The code below is self explanatory, I hope.

I'm only learning ionic now and might be doing something rightfully dumb. please let me know if there's any other details that you require.

Here is [**My Output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKJqv.png). Any clue what I'm doing wrong ?

My html :-

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>

  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>Select your location</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="select-location">
  <ion-list radio-group>
    <ion-list-header *ngIf="!selectLocation">
      Where are you located?</ion-list-header>
    <ion-list-header *ngIf="selectLocation">
      Selected Location:
      <p [innerText]="selectLocation.name"></p>
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-radio
      *ngFor="let location of locations"
      (select)="selectLocation = location"
      [value]="location.code"
    >{{location.name}}
    </ion-radio>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

My ts:-

```
[import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

/*
  Generated class for the SelectLocationPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/select-location/select-location.html',
})
export class SelectLocationPage {
  public locations;
  constructor(public nav: NavController) {
    this.locations = \[
      {
        code: 1,
        name: 'Powai',
        pincode: '400076'
      },
      {
        code: 2,
        name: 'Chandivali',
        pincode: '400072'
      },
      {
        code: 3,
        name: 'Dadar',
        pincode: '400023'
      },
      {
        code: 4,
        name: 'Colaba',
        pincode: '400001'
      }
    \];
  }
}][1]
```

Comment: The text goes inside of an `<ion-label>` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's some weird looking code; it should look more like [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/radio/RadioGroup/):

```
 <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectLocationName">
     <ion-list-header *ngIf="!selectLocationName">
         Where are you located?</ion-list-header>
     <ion-list-header *ngIf="selectLocationName">
         Selected Location:
         <p> {{ selectLocationName }}</p>
     </ion-list-header>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let location of locations">
         <ion-label>{{ location.name }}</ion-label>
         <ion-radio [value]="location.name "</ion-radio>
     </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```